# Is there a performance advantage to using clear method of a dictonary or set?

Tags: python

I just discovered that in Python dictionaries and sets both have a `clear` method. The method literally just removes all the entries from the object.

Is there a good reason, or even situation, where it makes sense to call `foo.clear()` rather than `foo = {}`, or `foo = set()`?

I can imagine it might work more efficiently for garbage collection, but it seems to violate "*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*"

Comment: Doing `foo = {}` and `foo.clear()` are not equivalent. One assigns `foo` to a **_new_** object, the other clears the entries in the **_existing_** object.

Comment: It doesn't violate "one obvious way" because they do different things.

Comment: You may wish to continue to use the same set object.

Comment: What if you have multiple variables referencing the same dictionary? `foo = {}` would only update a single variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple references to the same set object, only `clear()` can empty the set without having to re-assign.

Compare:

```
>>> def clear(s):
...     s.clear()
...
>>> def clear_assignment(s):
...     s = set()
...
>>> foo = {'bar', 'baz'}
>>> clear_assignment(foo)
>>> foo
{'baz', 'bar'}
>>> clear(foo)
>>> foo
set()
```

Assignment rebinds *one* name to a new `set()` object, while `set.clear()` removes everything from the mutable object without re-assignment, so you can continue to use other references to that set.

Comment: Ah, that seems so obvious now.

Comment: Part of the question was about garbage collection. I assume that this doesn't free up the memory instantly (or via `gc.collect()`) any differently than reassigning to an empty dictionary?

Comment: @roganjosh: Python uses reference counting; objects are immediately deleted when their reference count drops to 0. The garbage collector is only there to break cycles. Using `set.clear()` just removes references, just like reassigning a name to something else does.

Comment: The issue I have is I have a dictionary key pointing to a 4GB object. Even if I assign a value of `""` against that key once I'm done, I can't release the memory of the original object. So in that sense, `clear()` won't help, as I understand your answer.

Comment: @roganjosh: no, clear won't help; you have other references elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

There could be other references to this object. If you replace your reference by a new object, the other references will still point to the original dictionary/set.

Answer (score 0):

foo={} does not delete the object, just references foo to a new empty object (the old one still remains though if other variables still reference to it).
So, foo.clear() is memory efficient and this is the preferable way to do it.

Comment: "the old one still remains" only if there is a another reference to it, otherwise won't it be garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. If it is not referenced by other variables, then it is garbage! I will update my answer, thanks!